# Erlang Distribution parameter related

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, inference, gamma-distribution

We know the Gamma distribution has two parameters typically referred to as the shape and the scale. These are denoted a and b, or α and β.

When the shape parameter is an integer then it is known as the Erlang Distribution.

What is the example of integer and not integer parameters difference with and example?

Answer (score 1):

A Gamma G(***a***,b) distribution with an integer shape ***a*** corresponds to the distribution of the sum of ***a*** iid Exponential Exp(b) variates. This property obviously fails to hold when ***a*** is not an integer.